# Simple MySQL query and comparison

Tags: php, mysql

I've seen many questions like this on stack overflow, but I want to know why my code won't work. It makes perfect (logical) sense. Can anyone please explain to me what code I would have to write to actually complete the if statement I have in mind?

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT confirmed FROM usernames WHERE username = '$username' AND password = '$password'")
if ($result==NULL)
echo 'Failure';
```

I'm attempting this in php.

**NOTE:**

confirmed in the DB is set to NULL, so the final echo should display.

Comment: What doesn't work? What error do you receive? What do you expect it to return? Any sample data? More information required.

Comment: $result is a resource, not a/the field/s. In case of failure it is false, else it contains the resource you need to fetch, using f.ex. mysql_fetch_array()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable `$result` contains an internal representation of the result of the query (as returned by the [`mysql_query()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) function). To get the actual value you need to use another function, like [`mysql_fetch_assoc()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php) or [`mysql_result()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-result.php). Kind of like this:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT confirmed FROM usernames WHERE username = '$username' AND password = '$password'");
$conf = mysql_result($result, 0, 0);
if ($conf == NULL){
    echo 'Failure';
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the code, but most importantly, thank you for the explanation. Very helpful. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to fetch a row!

```
$row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
if($row[0] == NULL) 
{
    echo 'failure';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this....

```
/*Add die for check if query has error */
/*Put Limit 0,1 for fetch only single row*/
$result = mysql_query("SELECT confirmed FROM usernames WHERE username = '$username' AND password = '$password' Limit 0,1") or die(mysql_error());

if($result){
  /*check if query return result or not according sql cond*/
  if(mysql_num_rows($result) == 0){
    echo "No Record Found";
    exit();
    }
  /*Assign confirmed index value to a varriable $condirmed*/  
 while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
      $confirmed = $row['confirmed'];
   }
    if($confirmed == 'NULL'){
       echo "Failure";
    }
}
```